# Ломается JS, если открываю popup, в котором страница, с которой открывается popup. Можно ли указать область работы для JS для конкретного файла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! У меня такая проблема.
Есть карточки с товарами. У них есть кнопка "Быстрый просмотр". По нажатию на которую открывается popap со страницей товара (с небольшими деталями - за счет `Request::initial()->is_ajax()` (это из Kohana)). 
Есть страница товара. На ней рассматривается одна карточка. И внизу вывод карточек "Похожие товары".
Если я на странице товара нажму на быстрый просмотр в одной из карточек "Похожие товары", то весь JS ломается.
Хочу сделать условие - если количество `popup > 0`, то все селекторы JS (JQuery) на странице применяются не к документу, а к popup. То есть, `$('.my-block')` вот этот селектор будет искаться не у документа, а внутри popup. Реально ли такое сделать, не переписывая практически весь JS-код?

Answer (score 0):

У jQuery есть параметр - [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). Вставляйте туда переменную, которая будет принимать `document` или элемент-контейнер попапа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что мне нужно. А можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы указать всего один раз контекст? Что-то типа этого...

$('.context') {
... мои функции ...
}

Comment: Нет. Придется во все вызовы `$('ваш селектор')` добавить второй параметр. Но это не должно быть проблемой. Шаблон замены достаточно однозначный.